# Per widget on sidebar, output custom html with widget content

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and it's all complicated to me, but a client has asked I design a WordPress compatible theme for him from the given theme. I've got most of the bits and bobs done but I still don't understand how I'd get wordpress to output custom html in the way I wish... For example, I have this code here which is to be a "widget" on the sidebar, however I can't find out how I'd get wordpress to output a code similar to this so that it'd be compatible with the theme..

```
  <div class="panelfive" id="panel3">
    <h4>WIDGET NAME</h4>
    <div id="panel2-body" class="panel_body">
    <ul>
    WIDGET CONTENT
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually themes will have a sidebar.php or similar, but it's not really necessary unless you want to make it modular. A wordpress theme is really just PHP, so you can throw that HTML in page.php and it will load anytime a page is loaded.

Check out a couple of references:

General reference for theme development--many pages and sub-pages: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

A visual representation of what a wordpress theme looks like, and the related files: http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/